# Conditional Rendering If else not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

I had created a LWC Component with conditional rendering on lightning Navigation bar.
It is not rendering the second part ("Hello showCustomerDetails!") text. Could you please help me with the code part

I have pasted the code below.

**Html File**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-size_full">
            <div style="width: 200px;">
                <lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item="recent" onselect={changeHandleAction}>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Customer Support">
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Profile" name="Profile"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Customer" name="Customer"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Case" name="Case"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-overflow>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Knowledge" name="Knowledge"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Reports" name="Reports"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Dashboard" name="Dashboard"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    </lightning-vertical-navigation-overflow>
                </lightning-vertical-navigation>
            </div>
            <template if:true={showProfileDetails}>
                <div class="slds-col slds-var-p-around_small">
                    Hello showProfileDetails!
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:true={showCustomerDetails}>
                <div>
                    Hello showCustomerDetails!
                </div>
                <div>
                    Hello showKnowledgeDetails!
                </div>
                <div>
                    Hello showCaseDetails!
                </div>
            </template>    
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS File**

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomerSupportDetails extends LightningElement {

    @track category = '';
    @track showProfileDetails = false;
    @track showKnowledgeDetails = false;
    @track showCustomerDetails = false;
    @track showCaseDetails = false;
    

    changeHandleAction(event){
        this.category = event.detail.name;
        alert(this.category)
        if (this.category =  'Profile'){
            this.showProfileDetails = true;
        }else if(this.category = 'Customer'){
            this.showCustomerDetails = true;
            this.showProfileDetails = false;
        }else if(this.category = 'Case'){
            this.showCaseDetails = true;
        }else if(this.category = 'Knowledge'){
            this.showKnowledgeDetails = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `if:true` directive is deprecated, and you should instead be using the `lwc:if`directive. That's not the issue, but it is worth mentioning. Also, you don't need `@track`

Comment: Also, you're missing a semicolon in your Javascript after the `alert()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like this is a simple case of using *assignment* (singe equals, `=`) when you need to use *equality comparison* (double or triple equals, `==` / `===`)

That is, in your Javascript...

This is wrong
`if (this.category = 'Profile'){`

And this is what you should have
`if (this.category == 'Profile'){`

and be sure to apply that same fix to the rest of your else ifs (which exhibit the same issue).

Comment: Thank you it is was a silly mistake